# How to update Safari when no updates seem to be available?

Tags: safari, software-update

Hi,

I have MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Safari 12.1.2 but I want to update to Safari latest version. However I cant find any update for that on the update screen. Does it mean I can update to anything newer than that anymore?

Thank you.

Comment: The later versions of Safari requires later versions of macOS.

Comment: anyway to bypass that?

Comment: What Mac do you have? I don't know of any that are stuck at Sierra. High Sierra was  a 'stopping point' for many, Mojave for some others. That may get you as far as Safari 13 or even 14, but as in my answer below, webm & webp will still be problematic.

Comment: Its a MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because virtualizing macOS on non-Apple hardware is against the license.

Comment: @MarcWilson, maybe you flagged for closure on the wrong question?  I’m not seeing anything related to virtualizing and/or non-Apple hardware.

Comment: @Allan See the fifth comment made by the OP to the given answer.

Comment: It doesn’t invalidate the *question* because it’s not actually about virtualizing on unsupported hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Safari versions are tied directly to your version of macOS. There is some overlap, so a new version will usually be compatible with last year's OS, though maybe not the year before. They're not served independently, like 'regular' apps.

Once things stop working [webm & webp are both going to be problematic] you'll have to switch to another browser, one not tied directly to your macOS version.

Comment: Just one of the myriad of reasons I don't use browsers tied to the OS.  Back in the day it was IE.  Now it's Safari.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still on Safari 14… it's starting to get issues. I haven't found another I'd prefer, though, yet. Not that I'm actively searching, but every so often I try one of the others, just to see.

Comment: I vacillate between Edge and Firefox.  There are features that I just love that come standard with Edge (vertical tabs) but FF requires a 3rd party plugins.  Edge performs better than FF, but isn't available on FreeBSD.  Firefox is available on every platform but suffers with performance.

Comment: Yeah, Edge is EoL too on Mojave. They're trying to sell me Chrome instead, which I do use on occasion, but I'm not a Google fan at all.

Comment: To be honest, I dont own a Mac. I installed it on a vmware virtualized environment. But its supposed to work the same. The only reason I did this is because I need a Mac in order to debug a webpage since I am a webdeveloper.

Comment: Then that makes it completely off-topic here. We do not support unlicensed installs. Plus, you're not going to be able to debug anything with a macOS so far out of date. Sierra is like trying to debug on WinXP.